# Bourns PSL Snap-In Connector?

Tags: connector, components, potentiometer

I want to build a small console with the Bourns PSL slide potentiometers (nothing big, it's a just-for-fun project). Unfortunately, I couldn't find the right connector on their website.

The [datasheet](https://www.bourns.com/docs/product-datasheets/psl.pdf?sfvrsn=9f9b77f6_5) doesn't seem to have the complete measurements (the bottom opening has no dimensions). I did search on their website but it looks like they only have spring loaded battery connectors.

So my question: Can anyone recommend a connector that fits the Bourns PSL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Bottom of your datasheet page 2.[image]

Comment: Yes, but where can I get a matching housing for this connector? I can't seem to find the right one :/

Comment: Which configuration do you have?

Comment: Looking at the drawings and pictures it appears they are using JST headers so the 4 position would be a connector such as PHR-4 https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/jst-sales-america-inc/PHR-4/455-1164-ND/608606

Comment: I've got Configuration 1, I'll buy a few of the ones you specified, seems like they could fit! Thanks!! :)